# Run SSIS/SSDT on app server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, enterprise, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-bi

My company is insisting that we not run SSIS/SSDT jobs on the DB server, but instead run them on an app server and since they're not offering any assistance how this possible I'm trying come up with ways to do it.  Here are my ideas so far, but would like to know of any approaches tried that work.

- Install SSDT2013 on the app server and use the 32bit db it creates to
  schedule and run jobs on the DB server
- Use VBS (scripts) to launch the packages
- Use DMO to launch jobs

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they want them to run on the app server then they will need to buy a SQL license for it.

Start there and see if they will run them on the db server!

Comment: I was thinking that by using a std version, we'd have all we need, so I'll run that by them.

thanks